# using variable length argument and want to let user give the actual argument of flexible size

Tags: python

want to give user the control to input flexible number of arguments

```
def add(*y):
    c=0
    for j in y:
        c+=j
    print(c)
d=[]
n=int(input('give length of numbers you want to add'))
for i in range(n):
    c=int(input('give the input-'))
    d.append(c)
add()
```

please tell me what should I pass as an actual argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add` takes any number of arguments, e.g.

```
add()
add(5)
add(5, 8, 11, 45)
```

Since you have the arguments in a list (in variable `d`), you can unpack them this way:

```
add(*d)
```

---

Let me clarify what the `*` does. It can be used in two places: in function definition and in function calls.

In function definition, `*` is used for making it possible to have a function which takes an arbitrary number of arguments.

For example, this function takes 2 arguments `x` and `y` and an arbitrary number of other arguments:

```
def func(x, y, *other_arguments):
    print('x', x)
    print('y', y)
    print('other', other_arguments)
```

See how it behaves in the example:

```
>>> func(5, 6)
x 5
y 6
other ()
>>> func(5, 6, 7)
x 5
y 6
other (7,)
>>> func(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
x 5
y 6
other (7, 8, 9)
```

As you can see, all *other arguments* are packed into a tuple and stored into the `other_arguments` variable.

When calling a function, the opposite can be done, i.e. a tuple or a list of values can be unpacked to be called as arguments. See this example:

```
def calculate_sum(a, b, c):
    print('{} + {} + {} = {}'.format(a, b, c, a + b + c))
```

It can be called with 3 arguments:

```
>>> calculate_sum(1, 2, 3)
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
```

or with one list unpacked into 3 arguments:

```
>>> values = [5, 6, 7]
>>>
>>> calculate_sum(*values)
5 + 6 + 7 = 18
```

Comment: thanks bro...but can you explain what this *d is exactly doing in add(*d)....what does this * do?

Comment: @QuamerNasim Take a look at Python documentation on [Arbitrary Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can condense what you wrote into something like below :

```
>>> def add(*y):
...     c = 0
...     d = []
...     for i in y:
...             d.append(i)
...             c += i
...     print(d)
...     return c
...
```

You can pass arguments like this, this will print the input values stored in the list d and the sum of the input values stored in c.

```
>>> add(5,6,7,8)
[5, 6, 7, 8]
26
```

Comment: read my question bro...you defined a complete new problem...i did not asked for this...check it again...but thanks for your effort